# SMIL file xml isn't e4x friendly?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x, osmf, smil

I'm loading in a smil file (follows the xml format) and it won't let me select properties via name (eg. `xml.body`) instead I can only access the data by `xml.child(0)`.

I've tried `xml.child('body')`, but still nothing. Anyone know a quick workaround? I would like to be able to access `xml.head.(@name=='rtmpPlaybackbase')` and the XMLList `xml.body.switch.video`

```
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
<head>
   <meta name="title" content="myStream"/>
   <meta name="httpBase" content="http://mydomain.com/"/>
   <meta name="rtmpPlaybackBase" content="http://mydomain.com/"/>
</head>
<body>
   <switch>
      <video src="myStream500K@54552" system-bitrate="500000"/>
      <video src="myStream900K@54552" system-bitrate="900000"/>
      <video src="myStream1500K@54552" system-bitrate="1500000"/>
   </switch>
</body>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, close your start tag , in the end with . Let's say you have it now like this:

```
var xml:XML = new XML('<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language"><head><meta name="title" content="myStream"/><meta name="httpBase" content="http://mydomain.com/"/><meta name="rtmpPlaybackBase" content="http://mydomain.com/"/></head><body><switch><video src="myStream500K@54552" system-bitrate="500000"/><video src="myStream900K@54552" system-bitrate="900000"/><video src="myStream1500K@54552" system-bitrate="1500000"/></switch></body></smil>');
```

Then if you trace the length of xml.body, it gives 0.

```
trace(String(xml.body).length); //traces 0
```

This is mainly because you have to use xml namespace:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language");
```

Now use this namespace to reach your tags in the xml:

```
trace(String(xml.ns::body).length); //traces 272
```

So `xml.ns::TAGNAME` is how you reach it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +answer +1 for quickness -- This worked without adding the close tag (shouldn't need one on the declaration?) However, I marked it as the answer because I completely forgot to use the namespace. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note - you have to use an actual string (eg. "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language") for the name space. I tried xml.namespaceDeclarations()[0] and it said the ns wasn't defined. So stick to how he gave the answer and you should be good!

Comment: Okay, last note.. I added [code] default xml namespace = ns [/code] because xml.ns::body.ns::switch throws an error due to switch being a reserved keyword. instead setup the default ns and you can do xml.body['switch'] GL all.